# Get GA4 report from frontend with OAuth2

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I check the documentation [Data API V1 (Preview)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) for GA4, it doesn't mentioned anything about supporting client side application as [Reporting V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js). Is there similar feature in **Data API V1** but just without documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Yangjun,

You may find this [sample code for node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-analytics-data/blob/master/samples/quickstart_oauth2.js) useful. More Oauth2 samples for the Data API are coming soon.